# Removing rows with nan values in recarrays of object datatype

Tags: numpy, nan, recarray

Here is my input:

```
data = np.array ( [ ( 'a2', 'b1', 'c1' ), ( 'a1', 'b1', 'c1' ), ( 'a2', np.NaN, 'c2' ) ], dtype = [ ( 'A', 'O' ), ( 'B', 'O' ), ( 'C', 'O' ) ] ) . view ( np.recarray)
```

I want this as the output:

```
rec.array ( [ ( 'a2', 'b1', 'c1' ), ( 'a1', 'b1', 'c1' ) ], dtype = [ ( 'A', 'O'), ( 'B', 'O' ), ( 'C', 'O' )  ] )
```

I have tried:

```
data [ data [ 'B' ] ! = np.NaN ] . view ( np.recarray )
```

but it doesn't work.

```
data [ data [ 'A' ] ! = 'a2' ] . view ( np.recarray )
```

gives the desired output.

Why is this method not working for `np.NaN`? How do I remove rows containing `np.NaN` values in recarrays of object datatype? Also, `~np.isnan()` doesn't work with object datatype.

Comment: There are 2 issues.  `x == np.nan` is always False.  `nan` does not equal anything else including `np.nan`.  `np.isnan` is the correct test for `nan`.  But it only works on a float `dtype` array., not on object or strings. You need to write a function that conditionally applies `isnan` and doesn't choke on strings.  Then apply that iteratively to each field.

Comment: Why does your array contain `np.nan` instead of `nan` strings?  With the string value, the dtype could be `U3` (or `S3) and you could do `data['A']!='nan'` tests.  `np.nan` is a special float value, that in the context of strings just gives headaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that applies `np.isnan`, but does not choke on a string):

```
def foo(item):
    try:
        return np.isnan(item)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

And use `vectorize` to make a function that will apply this to the elements of an array, and return a boolean array:

```
f=np.vectorize(foo, otypes=[bool])
```

With your `data`:

```
In [240]: data = np.array ( [ ( 'a2', 'b1', 'c1' ), ( 'a1', 'b1', 'c1' ), ( 'a2' , np.NaN, 'c2' ) ], dtype = [ ( 'A', 'O' ), ( 'B', 'O' ), ( 'C', 'O' ) ] )
In [241]: data
Out[241]: 
array([('a2', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', nan, 'c2')], 
      dtype=[('A', 'O'), ('B', 'O'), ('C', 'O')])
In [242]: data['B']
Out[242]: array(['b1', 'b1', nan], dtype=object)

In [243]: f(data['B'])
Out[243]: array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [244]: data[~f(data['B'])]
Out[244]: 
array([('a2', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c1')], 
      dtype=[('A', 'O'), ('B', 'O'), ('C', 'O')])
```

==============

The simplest way to perform this test removeal over all fields is to just iterate on field names:

```
In [429]: data    # expanded with more nan
Out[429]: 
array([('a2', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', nan, 'c2'),
       ('a2', 'b1', nan), (nan, 'b1', 'c1')], 
      dtype=[('A', 'O'), ('B', 'O'), ('C', 'O')])
```

The `f` function applied to each field and collected into an array:

```
In [441]: np.array([f(data[name]) for name in data.dtype.names])
Out[441]: 
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Use `any` to get the columns where any item is True:

```
In [442]: np.any(_, axis=0)
Out[442]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [443]: data[_]    # the ones with nan
Out[443]: 
array([('a2', nan, 'c2'), ('a2', 'b1', nan), (nan, 'b1', 'c1')], 
      dtype=[('A', 'O'), ('B', 'O'), ('C', 'O')])
In [444]: data[~__]   # the ones without
Out[444]: 
array([('a2', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a1', 'b1', 'c1')], 
      dtype=[('A', 'O'), ('B', 'O'), ('C', 'O')])
```

(In Ipython `_` and `__` contain the results shown in the previous `Out` lines.)

`tolist` converts the array into a list of tuples (the records of a structured array are displayed as tuples):

```
In [448]: data.tolist()
Out[448]: 
[('a2', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a2', nan, 'c2'),
 ('a2', 'b1', nan),
 (nan, 'b1', 'c1')]
```

`f` as a `vectorized` function is able to apply `foo` to each element (apparently it does `np.array(data.tolist(), dtype=object)`)

```
In [449]: f(data.tolist())
Out[449]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [ True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
In [450]: np.any(_, axis=1)
Out[450]: array([False, False,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I've never tried this combination of `tolist` and `vectorize` before.  Vectorized functions iterate over their inputs, so they don't offer much of a speed advantage over explicit iterations, but for tasks like this it sure simplifies the coding.

Another possibility is to define `foo` to operate across the fields of a record.  In fact I discovered the `tolist` trick when I tried to apply `f` to a single record:

```
In [456]: f(data[2])
Out[456]: array(False, dtype=bool)
In [458]: f(list(data[2]))
Out[458]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [459]: f(data[2].tolist())
Out[459]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: how do I drop all the rows containing NaN in one go rather than taking on one variable at a time? @hpaulj

Comment: My test works with one field at a time.  We'd have take a logical combination across fields, `any(f(A),f(B),etc)` or within `foo` itself.

Comment: I've added a couple of examples of applying this test to the whole structured array.  It's easier than I thought.